# Error while connecting with webservice

Tags: android, httpconnection

### i write this code in main.java

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try{
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://way2tutorial.com/json/index.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             InputStream is = entity.getContent();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            }
```

### and also include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in manifestfile

but there is a error when run android application error in `http`

> connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: cut and paste the error - because it certainly isn't what you listed

Comment: Post full stack trace...

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: This is not your original error. Post your full log-cat value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Honeycomb (v 3.0) you are not allowed to perform Networking task on main thread. Try doing it on AsyncTask or if you are really doing some trivial task try changing your minsdkversion in manifest lower than 11.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything via network on the main thread of your application. You must run it in a new thread, I recommend to do it within an AsyncTask. Look here for an example - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

This error because you are executing networking task in event thread. New Sdk version forced developer to execute networking tasks into other thread than event thread. To resolve this issue, create a separate thread for that purpose,

Handler and AsyncTask are the ways to handle these types of tasks in other thread than EventThread,

See following links to understand event threads, and networking tasks implementation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Honeycomb i.e 3.0 [you are no longer allowed to do network operations in application's main thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). You should create a separate thread to do network operations. Try the following code instead:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://way2tutorial.com/json/index.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
    }
}.start();
```